# Nodejs receiving email and redirecting to gmail email address

Tags: node.js, email

So i have an website, `abc.com`. If someone sends an email at `support@abc.com` i want to receive it at gmail address or whatever address i chose. Then if i reply to that email it in gmail then it should send either using gmail or mandrill. And `from` of the email should show up as `support@abc.com`.

This is my first time tackling email. And i have no clue.

So far i understand i need something to take emails in, send emails out, and then there is smtp server.

I get that nodemailer fulfils the role needed by two of the first things..But rest is confusing.

I know this sounds vague but as front end jquery dev i never thought of this much. So be patient and understand like with http protocol i have not much of understanding on this. This question could be many questions however i don't know what those question need to be.

Comment: i found a better way: 1st made domain name registrar to forward emails to my gmail address...then configured gmail settings to send emails support@company.com to which it send verification at. At which my dn company forwared it back to me which i verified by clicking link. Now i do appear as i should.

Comment: Can you migrate abc.com to use Google Apps? It would solve some problems. You can use node-imap to read emails from a (system) mailbox.